# C# WinForms - This causes a endless loop: await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

Tags: c#, token, infinite-loop, msal

Whole function:

```
public static async Task<SaslMechanismOAuth2> AuthenticateMS365Async(Benutzer user)
{
    if (!user.UseImapM365 && !user.UsePopM365)
        return null;

    SaslMechanismOAuth2 oauth2 = null;
    string[] scopes = new string[] { };

    if (user.UseImapM365)
    {
        scopes = new string[]
        {
            "email",
            "offline_access",
            "https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All", // Only needed for IMAP
        };
    }
    else if (user.UsePopM365)
    {
        scopes = new string[]
        {
            "email",
            "offline_access",
            "https://outlook.office.com/POP.AccessAsUser.All",  // Only needed for POP
        };
    }
    var options = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
    {
        ClientId = user.MS_CLIENTID,
        TenantId = user.MS_TENANTID,
        RedirectUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient"
    };

    var storageProperties = new StorageCreationPropertiesBuilder("merlin_msal_cache.dat", MsalCacheHelper.UserRootDirectory).Build();

    var publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
        .CreateWithApplicationOptions(options)
        .Build();

    var cacheHelper = await MsalCacheHelper.CreateAsync(storageProperties);
    cacheHelper.RegisterCache(publicClientApplication.UserTokenCache);

    AuthenticationResult authToken;
    try
    {
        authToken = await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, EMailService.MS_AuthAccount).ExecuteAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        //Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        authToken = await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

        var accounts = await publicClientApplication.GetAccountsAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
        EMailService.MS_AuthAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(authToken.Account.Username, authToken.AccessToken);
    return oauth2;
}
```

This function works. I tested it in one part of my program, but somehow ends in a infinite loop in another part of my program (gets stuck).

```
authToken = await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
```

This is the part where it gets stuck in a infinite loop.

I really have no clue what it could be.

That the AcquireTokenInteractive works equally in different parts of a program and doesn't show erratic behavior?

I checked the input many times and it is absolutely indentical (the Client-ID and Tenant ID and such).

I am clueless right now...

Comment: Have you tried putting a try/catch block around all of the code in this function (with a break-point or trace statements)? I've seen stuff like this when my code in the catch block, was quietly throwing another exception.

Comment: @tgolisch Tested. It never jumps in the catch. It is a proper infinite loop.

Comment: How about the return path for your oauth. Is it possible that after MS does authentication, the return path isn't coming back to your current thread? I've experienced stuff like that before when using MS/Azure to do 3PA.

Comment: @tgolisch not sure. The issue is this code works at one point in my program, but doesnt at another point. This seems to suggest that the path I use (which is the same in both situations) should work.

Comment: Do you always test in the same order (part 1, then part 2)? If you switch the order (part 2, then part 1) still the same outcome?

Comment: @tgolisch yes, same outcome. I think its something about the UI thread in the background. But no idea.